# How to format datetime as week in line chart bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I m creating a Line chart using bokeh.

I need to insert on X axis the number of week of the year. So now I have this code:

```
sql = """
    SELECT   DATEPART(week,dataOra) as DateTime,AVG(valore) as Valore 
    FROM AA_V_BV_Sfere
    WHERE IdPerson = ? and idSfera =? 
    Group by DATEPART(week,dataOra)
"""
dfSfere = pd.read_sql(sql, odbc_cnn, params=[int(13), int(1))
plotSfera = figure(plot_width=int(850), plot_height=int(165), tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,xwheel_zoom,save", title=nomeSfera,                               x_axis_type="datetime")
plotSfera.y_range.start = 0
plotSfera.y_range.end = rangeMax + 5
plotSfera.line(x='DateTime', y='Valore', color="navy", alpha=1, source=sourceSfere)
plotSfera.circle(x='DateTime', y='Valore', color="navy", alpha=1, source=sourceSfere)
plotSfera.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days=f"%G/%G")
hover = HoverTool(
   tooltips=[
      ("Data", "@DateTime{%d-%m-%Y}"),
      ("Valore", "@Valore")
   ],
   formatters={
      '@DateTime': 'datetime',
      '@Valore': 'printf',
   },
)
plotSfera.add_tools(hover)
```

The result is this:
[Image result][1]

As you can see on X axis, there are items with milliseconds but I need to have the number of week.

Another point is on Hover element:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I need to have near "Date" label, the start date and end date of the week.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nICe0.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBiYh.jpg